Nested div blocking scroll in parent div
I have a problem. I have a div, called container, which is my main scrolling container, and inside, I have a few pages. On the first page, is my logo (in the aspect ratio 4.37:1), but when I scroll over   my logo (I position the scroll wheel over it), it doesn't scroll. I'm not using an <img> element as I need to have it change using the @media (orientation: portrait), but I've sorted that out
Why is the nested div homelogo blocking scrolling for the (2x) parent container?


body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-padding-top: 7.5vh;
    flex-basis: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#logoscreen {background-color: black;}


.container > div {
    height: 92.5vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 7.5vh;
top: 0px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
}

#homelogo {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
}
#homelogo:is(.top) {
    top: 0.25vw;
    left: 50vw;
    width: 45vh;
    height: calc(45vh/4.37);
}
#homelogo:not(.top) {
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: min(300vh, 100vw);
    height: calc(min(300vh, 100vw)/4.37);
}
<body>  
    <div id="container" class="container">
        <div id="logoscreen">
            <div id="navbar"></div>
            <div id="homelogo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 100px; background-color: white;">2nd Page</div>
</body>



Why is the nested div homelogo blocking scrolling for the (2x) parent container?

EDIT:
I have found the issue is due to the overflow-y property - when I set it to be scroll, it is broken, but when I remove the line overflow-y: scroll, it breaks. And for anyone that asks, if I don’t put overflow scroll, neither scroll snapping, nor hiding the scroll bar work anymore, and (even though I didn’t include them - I removed them for debug) they are still very important in the overall “look and feel” of the website.

I think you're missing a closing </div>

Yes, but that has not fixed it.
